# How to stop bash scripts from exit ing the window altogether

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit

When I write bash script and I have

```
exit;;
```

or

```
exit 0;;
```

the script not only exits but the window (or pane in the case of tmux panes) exits completely (goes away).

e.g.

```
while true; do
  read -p 'Run with -a (auto-correct) options?' yn
  case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) rubocop -a $@;;
    [Nn]* ) exit;;   # <--here exits window completely !
    * ) echo "Yes or No!";;
  esac
done
```

How can I prevent this?

My bashrc is:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups HISTSIZE=100000 HISTFILESIZE=200000
shopt -s histappend checkwinsize
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
test -f ~/.bash_functions.sh && . $_  # I can comment these out & it doesn't help
test -f ~/.bash_aliases && . $_
test -f ~/.eq_aliases && . $_
test -f ~/.git-completion.bash && . $_
test -f /etc/bash_completion && ! shopt -oq posix && . /etc/bash_completion
test -f ~/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh && . $_
ls --color=al > /dev/null 2>&1 && alias ls='ls -F --color=al' || alias ls='ls -G'
HOST='\[\033[02;36m\]\h'; HOST=' '$HOST
TIME='\[\033[01;31m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]'
LOCATION=' \[\033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"`'
BRANCH=' \[\033[00;33m\]$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS1=$TIME$USER$HOST$LOCATION$BRANCH
PS2='\[\033[01;36m\]>'
set -o vi # vi at command line
export EDITOR=vim
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH" # Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ # for meld mdd 4/19/2014
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)" # friendly for non-text files
[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -ge 4 ] && shopt -s autocd
#[ `uname -s` != Linux ] && exec tmux
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Are you running it as `scriptname` or `source scriptname` or `. scriptname`? The latter two are equivalent and will run it in the shell itself, not as a subprocess, so yes, `exit` will close the window if `SHLVL` is 1.

Comment: Using `.` but also finding that using `return;;` instead of `exit` will work

Comment: Yes, there you go. `return` only works in functions and sourced scripts, so if you're using `.` or `source`, use `return`.

Comment: Why are you not running the script as `./scriptname` (the easiest imHo) or `bash scriptname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` is what you are looking for.

`exit` terminates the shell process when called. As you are sourcing your shell scripts, they are run within your current shell. This means when a sourced shell scripts hits an `exit` it will terminate your shell.

`break` on the other hand merely leaves the current loop structure, the while loop in your case.

From the bash manual:

```
break

    break [n]

    Exit from a for, while, until, or select loop. If n is supplied, the
    nth enclosing loop is exited. n must be greater than or equal to 1.
    The return status is zero unless n is not greater than or equal to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

With an script named `scriptname.sh` which contains only this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script executed"
exit
```

Will make the shell where you are working close if the script is sourced.

To prevent that the whole window also close, start a new bash sub-shell by simply executing `bash`. The depth of sub-shells could be seen in the SHLVL variable:

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
3
```

If at that point you source the script above:

```
$ source ./scriptname.sh
script executed
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

As you can see, one instance of bash got closed.
The same will happen with `.`

```
$ . ./scriptname.sh
script executed
$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

If you source the script again at this level, the whole window will close. To avoid that call a new instance of bash.

A better way to run the program ./scriptname.sh is to make it executable:

```
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ chmod u+x scriptname.sh
$ ./scriptname.sh
script executed
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

Or even calling the script with the name of the shell:

```
$ bash ./scriptname
script executed
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```